# Получить главную страницу сайта (http запрос)

Tags: c++, http, get, winsock

Доброго времени суток. Начал разбираться с http запросами и возникли некие проблемы. Если на сайте example.com  есть страница index.html то запрос вида

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 
Host: www.example.com
```

возвращает код страницы html. Не могу понять, что делать, если на сайте index.php (изменённый запрос возвращает код 301).

```
HTTP/1.1 301 
...
Location: http://example.com/index.php
```

В этом коде в поле Location адрес, по которому расположена данная страница, но при запросе вида

```
GET http://example.com/index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

или

```
GET http://example.com/index.php HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.com
```

возвращается код 404.

### Как в данном случае сформировать запрос?

При попытке запроса вида

```
GET https://example.com/ HTTP/1.0 
Host: www.example.com
```

возвращает 403... я совсем запутался

Comment: запрос должен выглядеть так `GET /index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`. А 'example.com' - это куда подключаться сокетом. Если там http**s**, то и порт нужно выбрать 443.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно так же, как вы делали для html:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.0 
Host: www.example.com
```

Но если вы захотите подключаться по протоколу `https`, то учтите, что тут порт по умолчанию не 80, а 443, и принцип соединения уже совершенно иной. Реализовать его самостоятельно, боюсь, задача неподъемная; лучше использовать готовую библиотеку - например, [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: `протокол уже совершенно иной.` - простокол тот же, просто нужно сокет в ssl завернуть.

Comment: @KoVadim согласен,не так выразился. Имел в виду, что просто подключиться к порту и отправить `GET` не получится.

Comment: Да, спасибо, не обратил внимания на https